# Fullcalendar jQuery plugin by Adam Shaw Scrollbar issue

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am wondering if there is a way to customize the scroll bar for the fullcalendar jQuery plugin of Adam Shaw, when going to Day in the calendar I see a default scrollbar and I manage to quick fix it by modifying the height as follows:

$(’#calendar’).fullCalendar(‘option’, ‘contentHeight’, 800);

The problem is that I don't want it to disappear I just want to customize the scrollbar  like nicescroll.

Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little hacky - I am finding the closest DIV that has a class then traversing to the next div (which has the scrollbars) and enabling niceScroll on that element. It would be easier if the container that scrolled had a class or an ID on it.

Once you include nicescroll you can add this to your calendar initialization:

```
viewDisplay: function(view) { 
     $('.fc-agenda-divider').next('div').niceScroll();
     }
```

Something like this

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            viewDisplay: function(view) { 
        $('.fc-agenda-divider').next('div').niceScroll();
        })
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsbin.com/ugepus/1/

[image: Screenshot of this element]

Comment: i see it working on your example but i dont seem to find the fc-agenda-divider anywhere on my side

Comment: See my screenshot of the element directly from the jquery fullcalendar website using Chrome dev tools.

Comment: add my code here: 
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ //re-initialize the calendar
                header: h,
viewDisplay: function(view) { 
     $('.fc-agenda-divider').next('div').niceScroll();
     },